# Excel: Conditional Formatting a cell based on an roster on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I'm new to using excel for work, I need to make an easy to read sheet where we can type in an employee's name and the conditional formatting will check the roster on say Sheet2 then format the cell on sheet1 (the one with the employee's name) to match the manager name in the roster (that way there are only say 6 different colors of cells) - I will also need to count the number of employees in sheet1 per manager, so I was thinking I would use a VLOOKUP in the column to the right then hide it to make it easy to read. I really don't know where to start here, can anyone help? I've added some images so hopefully this makes sense.

This is where the employee name should be color coded:

[image: Sheet1]

And this is the employee "roster":

[image: Sheet2]

Comment: What exactly need to be colour coded and counted? Please also add screenshot with desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For Conditional Formatting cells to different color for each Manager:

Manager1: Red

Manager2: Yellow

Manager3: Blue

Manager4: Green

You can select the Range ***D4:D6*** and go to ***Home***- ***Conditional Formatting***- ***New Rule...***- ***Use a Formula to determine which cells to format***- set the ***Format..*** and enter the Formula:

> =VLOOKUP(D4,Roster!$A$1:$B$23,2,FALSE)="Manager1"
> =VLOOKUP(D4,Roster!$A$1:$B$23,2,FALSE)="Manager2"
> =VLOOKUP(D4,Roster!$A$1:$B$23,2,FALSE)="Manager3"
> =VLOOKUP(D4,Roster!$A$1:$B$23,2,FALSE)="Manager4"

[image]

2. For Count how many employee did the manage have, try to enter the formula:

> =COUNTIF(Roster!$B$2:$B$23,VLOOKUP(D4,Roster!$A$1:$B$23,2,FALSE))

[image]